# awk -e not an option. Recommend a suitable alternative?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, bash

I have a shell script that invokes `awk -e`, but the script is incompatible on Raspberry Pi (Jessie + PIXEL). Error text says that `-e is not an option`. It's my understanding that the version of `awk` running on Raspbian is somewhat outdated. Is there an alternative to using this command?

The context is to read out the size of an unzipped archive in kB:

```
UNZIP_SIZE=$(unzip -l $ZIP_PATH | tail -n 1 | awk -e '{print int($1/1024)}')
```

where:

`unzip -l` lists the .zip's contents, with the last line being the total, unextracted size.

`tail -n 1` grabs that last line

it's my understanding that:

```
awk -e ...
```

takes the last line as the input, selects the first 'argument' which in this case is the file size in bytes, and divides by 1024 to arrive at kB.

Comment: This is not a Pi question. `awk` is itself rather old, and implementations differ. None of the implementations or books I have support `-e`. I would just use `awk '{print int($1/1024)}'`

Comment: Thanks, @Milliways. I realise this question is probably directed more to the Super User forum.

Comment: Install `gawk`, it has the '-e' option.

Comment: I rolled with what Milliways suggested - I don't fully understand the -e option but it seems like it might have been redundant. If I run into problems I'll install `gawk`.

Comment: @Milliways I realise the question is not Pi specific but as you have answered the question is there any harm in formally making the comment an answer?